# How to snip pin off .05" pitch header

Tags: jtag, tools

What cutter will work for cutting a pin off a .05" pitch pin header? I need to do this to make a 9 pin Cortex debug header and the part is so small I'm not sure even a miniature cutter will be able to fit between the pins far enough to make the cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times you can push the pin out of the connector body instead of cutting it off. This would be applicable for connectors that are not already soldered to the circuit board.

Sometimes for small pins you can twist them off using a pair of needle nosed pliers.

Do note that cutting pins off with some cutter tools that have precision ground fine point jaws can be the death of the cutter. So use care when studying the problem and avoid being tempted to cut pins with your 70$ / pair Erem cutters.

Comment: Pushing pin out of the connector body worked great (if you remember to do it before it is assembled). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Exacto, Dremel, Needle Nose Pliers (hold and snap). Sometimes you have to sacrifice a pin.